# External power for compact camera?

Tags: battery, compact-cameras, power-supply, power

I would like to experiment with time lapses using compact cameras (like Coolpix S6300), as I don't want to put an extreme number of clicks on my DSLR for the moment.

Are there any solutions for powering compact cameras from an external battery?  I don't expect any manufacturer-approved solution to exist, but I am hoping that someone has developed a working hack, or maybe some companies even make a battery-shaped power adaptor.

The S6300 uses the EN-EL12 battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your camera and many of Nikon's current and past point-and-shoot models, the [Nikon EH-62F](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Power-Adapters/EH-62F-AC-Adapter.html) will do the trick.  Many other brands offer similar accessories for at least some of their models.

When the adapter offered has a plastic lump to replace the battery, it means the camera can't be powered using the USB port (if it has one) for anything except charging the battery, and many cameras don't even allow that.

I have a Panasonic ZS20 that has a similar arrangement: you buy the AC power supply which has a standard male coax connector on it, and a battery lump that pops into the camera and has a cord with a matching female connector on it.  I don't have the power supply handy, but I think it makes 8 or 9 VDC and I'm pretty sure the battery output is 3.6.  Mine would be easy to drive from a 5 VDC source with an adjustable DC-to-DC converter [like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BYTEHQO).

The connector on the Nikon adapter looks proprietary, and I have no idea what voltage it supplies.

Comment: I wonder how you found that.  I just spent 20 minutes googling in the hope of finding something like this!

Comment: @Szabolcs:  Some [light Google-fu](https://www.google.com/search?q=Coolpix+S6300+AC+Adapter).  Look under the "Accessories" tab.  I have similar kit for a couple of my cameras.

Comment: @Szabolcs:  Oops.  Meant to say look under the "Accessories" tab on the page for your camera on Nikon's website.

Comment: Is your kit also for Nikon cameras?  Do you know if the plug it uses is a special proprietary one or a standard USB?  (EN-EL12 uses less than 5 V).  I'm ultimately looking to power both the camera and a Raspberry Pi from a large USB-compatible 5 V external battery.

Comment: @Szabolcs:  I updated the answer with more details.